# adding alternate text to a programmatically created image

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have an ashx file that creates an image with text written on it.

```
//create the image for the string
Font f = new Font("Arial", 15F);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
SolidBrush whiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0,71,133));
SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
RectangleF canvas = new RectangleF(0, 0, 105, 45);
g.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, canvas);
context.Session["test"] = randomString;
g.DrawString(context.Session["test"].ToString(), f, blackBrush, canvas);
context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
b.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
```

When called, it creates the image I want, but realized that it doesn't have have an alt text option for accessibility purposes.

Any idea on how to add alternate text to an image?

In my aspx page I have this:

```
 <asp:Image ID="myImage" class="styleimage" src="ImageMaker.ashx" runat="server"/>
```

I have tried:

```
myImage.AlternateText = HttpContext.Current.Session["test"].ToString();
```

I receive a `NullReferenceException`.

This apparently happens because `Session["test"]` gets populated after the page load ( so the page loads, the image gets rendered, then the handler gets called).

How do I solve this?

Comment: An image file does not contain an "alt" text. Never has. Do you mean the `alt` attribute on an HTML image element?

Comment: Correct!  Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: What's that got to do with the image generation code you have posted then? I don't see _any_ HTML here.

Comment: Well since the image is being generated programatically, I was hoping there was a similar way to add the alternate attribute programatically as well.

Comment: Sure, there is. But you have not posted any ASP.NET markup or code. Where is the code you use to _display_ the image?

Comment: This code is located in my aspx file that calls the handler.
<asp:Image ID="myImage" class="styleimage" src="ImageMaker.ashx" runat="server"/>

Comment: So? Did you try the `AlternateText` attribute? You can set it in code behind.

Comment: Yes.  I have tried:  
myImage.AlternateText = HttpContext.Current.Session["test"].ToString();
I receive a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Meaning that either `Session` or `myImage` is `null` or that `"test"` doesn't exists. Where in the code have you done this?

Comment: I've inserted that code in my aspx.cs file - page_load
Session["test"] is gets populated in my ashx file

Comment: So, it gets populated _after_ the page loads (page loads, image gets rendered, handler gets called...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the session variable in your page_load and assign the `randomString` to it there.

You will then be able to access it in the handler to use in creating the image.

This way, you follow the timeline of the different events:

- Page loads
- Session variable gets created
- Image element on the page gets rendered
- Handler gets called
- Session variable is referenced to get the string
- Image gets generated
- Profit!

Answer (score 0):

The alt-text belongs to the img-tag which references the image your handler creates. Just put the alt tag there and you are good to go.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response.  Can you explain exactly where to put the alt tag that you were referring to?  Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to create the alt-tag at the same time as you create the image. I think you need to think about separation of responsibilites, one piece of code which is responsible for creating the image, and another one to display it. The display code is the code which contains the <asp:Image /> and it is here you should set the AlternateText.